# Move the given pattern from any where in string at the start position in regex

Tags: r, regex

Suppose the string is `x <- "4528383 validation 34567 validation 34567"`, I need to move the first pattern `"validation 34567"` to the start of the string.

How can I do that?

Expected output:

```
"validation 34567 4528383 validation 34567"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base R, use regex-groups and reorder them (from 1-2-3 to 2-1-3)

```
sub("(^.*)(validation 34567 )(.*$)", "\\2\\1\\3", x)

#[1] "validation 34567 4528383 validation 34567"
```

Comment: getting these :

Comment: > sub("(^.*)(validation [[:digit:]]+ )(.*$)", "\\1", df1$found2[4606])
[1] " 98597   98597   validation   98597"
> sub("(^.*)( validation [[:digit:]]+ )(.*$)", "\\1", df1$found2[4606])
[1] " 98597   98597   validation   98597"
> sub("(^.*)( validation [[:digit:]]+ )(.*$)", "\\1\\2", df1$found2[4606])
[1] " 98597   98597   validation   98597"
> sub("(^.*)( validation [[:digit:]]+ )(.*$)", "\\2\\1\\3", df1$found2[4606])
[1] " 98597   98597   validation   98597"

Comment: @ankit It works on the data you provided. Post some (more relevant) sample data, so we can properly test out answers.. use `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
library(stringr)
library(wrapr)

x = "MANY THINGS AAA BBB CCC 4528383 validation 34567 validation 34567"

x %.>%
  paste(
    str_extract(., 'validation \\d+'),
    str_remove(., 'validation \\d+')
  )
```

Output:

```
"validation 34567 MANY THINGS AAA BBB CCC 4528383  validation 34567"
```

Comment: not working , lets say i have many things in string and i want to move the position of "validation 34567" to the first place

Comment: I think it is working. Did you load libraries? Look eddited answer.

Comment: Hi I tried but still not getting the output. Let me put it in another way . Suppose the string is having pattern like "Accvuc  25743 validation 12345 validation 87654". Now i need to pull the first validation and the number which follows it. the place where first validation occur is not consistent in another rows of data frame, can you help me to fetch this out ?

Comment: My code always pull the first "validation <any number>" in front of the string.

Comment: Maybe provide sample of yours data frame with `dput()` function.

Comment: My data frame has these rows  "110231 validation 108871 validation 85933" , "21102 validation 93442 21232 validation 73769 26402 validation 127221 26402", "99763 99763 validation 99763 validation 99763","validation 199022 validation 122099 validation 12209 validation 199022 validation 199022 validation 122099"  ## each value separated by coma is a new row , I need to extract out the first validation and number which follows it for each row .

Comment: Please read about how to share data sample in StackOverflow with `dput()` function.